# How to set TimeZone using Powershell

Tags: powershell, timezone, windows-server-2008-r2

How can I set TimeZone using Powershell, on a Windows Server 2008 R2 target machine?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is how I do it in setup scripts...although our AD infrastructure would set this when the machine joins the domain anyway...I like to be thorough in my scripting :)

```
%windir%\system32\tzutil /s "Eastern Standard Time"
```

Comment: actually for Powershell remove the %windir%\system32\ as PS wont know how to handle it...you could use C:\Windows\System32\ instead

Comment: system32 is normally in your path so you don't need it at all. tzutil.exe works on any typical out of the box Windows machine (that has the application in system32 :)

Comment: The exact powershell equivalent is `& "$env:windir\system32\tzutil.exe" /s "Eastern Standard Time"` but agreed, you don't actually need system32

Answer (score 11):

At least in newer versions of Powershell (5.1 and later), there is a cmdlet.  See [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-timezone).

Set-TimeZone "Eastern Standard Time"

Older versions can find the script [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-TimeZone-function-b5ed93b5).

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell command
tzutil /g - to see current time zone
tzutil /l - list of time zones
tzutil /s "example" to change time zone

There are other commands to change the time zone I have explained it in my YouTube video https://youtu.be/JvLa5HjEjHM

Hope this will help you!!